# SAPUI5 error changing value in input with oData model

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I have an oData model in my application, this is one of the elements, which is binded to the view:

```
{  
   "SO_Id":1,
   "Customer_No":"1",
   "System_Status":false,
   "User_Status":false,
   "SO_Description":"drive seamless niches"
}
```

This is how I'm binding it to the view:

```
this.getView().bindElement({
    path: "/SO_Info('1')",
    model: "SO_List"
});
```

And I'm binding the properties like this (XML):

```
<Input value="{SO_List>SO_Description}"/>
```

It's displayed well but everytime I modify this input I get the following error in the chrome inspector:

> ManagedObject-dbg.js:3093 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at constructor.r._resolveGroup (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2630:233)
>       at constructor.r.setProperty (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2658:1241)
>       at constructor.O.setValue (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2120:106)
>       at constructor.P.setExternalValue (PropertyBinding-dbg.js:131)
>       at f.j.updateModelProperty (ManagedObject-dbg.js:3050)
>       at f.j.setProperty (ManagedObject-dbg.js:1067)
>       at f.a.setProperty (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2293:115)
>       at f.a.setValue (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2307:308)
>       at f.h.setValue (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2261:73)
>       at f.a.onChange (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3395), :2283:178)

However, the value is correctly changed in the model. Why I'm still getting an error?

Comment: Please show the coding where you do the binding.

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych I have updated the question

Comment: are you sure that view sees this model? if you call this.getView().getModel("SO_List") - will it return the correct model?

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych Yes, it does

Comment: Which ui5 version you use? Which kind of model?

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych 1.44 and oDataModel v2. May the problem reside in the mockserver I'm ucurrently using instead of real services? The method "_resolveGroup" from the control itself seems to have problem in this line: E = this.oMetadata._getEntityTypeByPath(k); (Being k = "SO_Info('1')") As it returns undefined

Comment: Where did you take the metadata? copied from existing service or "hand made" ? Can you share the metadata? It would be better if you can show the whole app in https://plnkr.co/ for instance.

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych It was an error in the metadata. Once it got fixed everything worked flawlessly.